# Magento: Is Tablerate Shipping based on the cart sum with or without taxes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a Shop with Products that have different Taxrates. Some have 0%, some 19% etc...

For Shipping im using Tablerates, for example:

up to 2000€ = 10€ shipping cost

up to or over 2400€ = 15€ shipping cost

Now comes the thing that at first i just want to understand, so there is not really a bug to fix here. I just need to know how it works to plan my tablerates accordingly.

I have orders with a total over 2400€ (incl. Tax), but the customer still gets the 10€ Shipping rate. This can only be if the System is using the Price without Tax to check against the table rates. Because only then would the price be in the Tablerate range for the lower rate. And yes i double checked the Tablerates Setup (not my first Magento Install).

**1) Is this assumption correct that table rates are checked against the total without taxes?**

**2) Is there a way to set up tablerates to check against the cart total including taxes?**

Anyone got any info on how that works in the background? I couldnt find anything as when youre searching the topic you mostly get tutorial on how to set up table rates.

Super thankful for any tipps or maybe other threads or places i could check for detailed infos on how that works.

*note: i use Magento 1.9.2.1*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: i guess your right. but this may still help others as i have gotten a answer that solved my question. is there a way to move a thread to magento.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Question 1:

It would appear to be without tax.

*Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRatesByAddress* calls *setPackageValue* to set the package value for the rate request.
This gets passed to *Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate::collectRates*.
*collectRates* subtracts free shipping from the package value.

Then *Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate::getRate* is called

```
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
$rate = $this->getRate($request);

...

public function getRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    return Mage::getResourceModel('shipping/carrier_tablerate')->getRate($request);
}
```

This calls *Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate::getRate* which binds the condition value to the query. (The condition name should be package_value in your case).

```
// Render condition by condition name
if (is_array($request->getConditionName())) {
    $orWhere = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($request->getConditionName() as $conditionName) {
        $bindNameKey  = sprintf(':condition_name_%d', $i);
        $bindValueKey = sprintf(':condition_value_%d', $i);
        $orWhere[] = "(condition_name = {$bindNameKey} AND condition_value <= {$bindValueKey})";
        $bind[$bindNameKey] = $conditionName;
        $bind[$bindValueKey] = $request->getData($conditionName);
        $i++;
    }

    if ($orWhere) {
        $select->where(implode(' OR ', $orWhere));
    }
} else {
    $bind[':condition_name']  = $request->getConditionName();
    $bind[':condition_value'] = $request->getData($request->getConditionName());

    $select->where('condition_name = :condition_name');
    $select->where('condition_value <= :condition_value');
}
```

While it is possible to modify the order, baseSubtotal should be before tax.
See *collectRatesByAddress*:

```
$request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($address->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()
    + $address->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
```

---

### As for your question 2.

As noted above, we have the data in the request, but we do not have an easy touchpoint.

One suggestion is to rewrite the *Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate* and override *getRate*. What you would do would be to set the **BaseSubtotal** to the **BaseSubtotalInclTax**, call parent, then reset the request.

```
public function getRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    // TODO: wrap in try catch, to reset the value ??
    // TODO: clone the request ??
    // TODO: Test This
    $oldPackageValue = $request->getPackageValue();
    $request->setPackageValue($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax());
    $returnvalue = Mage::getResourceModel('shipping/carrier_tablerate')->getRate($request);
    $request->setPackageValue($oldPackageValue);
    return $returnvalue;
}
```

This is hacky, but minimally intrusive. It should withstand unrelated changes without forcing you to modify the code.

Another method involves rewriting and modifying *Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate::getRate* to use the value you want.

**NOTE:** Neither of these methods are tested.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed feedback! this should be the thing to get the results.